# Unable to import java.lang.instrument in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, instrumentation

I am trying to import the Java Instrumentation library (java.lang.instrument) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html in my Android Studio project but it is complaining that it isn't able to find it.

From what I understand, this library should be built in to Java. While typing in java.lang, I do see existing classes under that package.

Does anyone know how I can use this specific class in Android Studio?

I have tried looking into the Gradle file where dependencies are declared but I am confused as java.lang is built into Java.

I was expecting the java.lang package in Android Studio to contain the Instrument class.

Comment: Android does not run Java bytecode or a Java JVM. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am trying to use this class to calculate the size of an object.